# When is useful to use std::any?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, std

I'm studing std::any costruct of the standard library of c++17 standard. But really i don't understand which are the the usecases in which is useful to use std::any instead of std::variant or any other costruct like template or a simple void* variable.

Someone can help me figure out these usecases?

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stdany-class-in-c/
some example mentioned here

Comment: [Boost.Program_options](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/program_options.html) uses something like a `std::map<std::string, std::any>` to store the programs input.